# Comparing functions with .toString() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tostring

Consider the ***snippet***

```
var dog1 = {id : 1, name : "Angus", age: 10};
var dog2 = {id : 1, name : "Angus", age: 10};

alert(dog1 == dog2);                      // ofcourse, false
alert(dog1.valueOf() == dog2.valueOf());  // ofcourse, false
```

In real life scenarios, ***dog1*** & ***dog2*** will be one and the same object.

Getting back to the real scenario,

I recently took over the project from some other developer, and for comparing objects, he has developed the following function to compare 2 objects. The project is developed purely in JavaScript.

***f() which checks for the equality of 2 objects*** -

```
function compareObjs(obj1, obj2) {

            var compare = function(objA, objB, param) {

                var param_objA = objA[param];
                var param_objB = (typeof objB[param] === "undefined") ? false : objB[param];

                switch(typeof objA[param]) {

                    case "object": return (compareObjs(param_objA, param_objB));
                    case "function": return (param_objA.toString() === param_objB.toString());
                    default: return (param_objA === param_objB);
                }

            }; // internal compare helper function

            for (var parameter_name in obj1)
                if (typeof obj2[parameter_name] === "undefined" || !compare(obj1, obj2, parameter_name))
                    return false;

            for (parameter_name in obj2)
                if (typeof obj1[parameter_name] === "undefined" || !compare(obj1, obj2, parameter_name))
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        var dog1 = {name : "Angus",

                bark : { frequency : "low" },
                age: 10
        };

        var dog2 = {name : "Angus",
                age: 10,
                bark : { frequency : "low" }
        };

        alert(compareObjs(dog1,dog2)); // true
```

I am confused at this line

```
case "function": return (param_objA.toString() === param_objB.toString());
```

Why for checking function equality, he has written the above code? Can someone shed light on this. Is it the correct way?

Comment: _In real life scenarios, dog1 & dog2 will be one and the same object._ In real life - yes, in Javascript - **no**. **Only comparing the same object reference with itself yields true**. ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects))

Comment: @hindmost: yes, i do know that they will be different in Javascript. I pretty covered this part in the first snippet. To overcome this kind of behaviour, the function has been developed.

Comment: _Why for checking function equality, he has written the above code?_ Obviously because Function's [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) method returns the string representation of its source code. So it would be a way of functions comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predecessor had good intentions, but unfortunately comparing the functions solely by their texts is not enough. You must also consider the environment in which the function was declared, because it might use closures (variables defined outside the function that the function uses).

Check out this example:

```
function getOne() {
  var x = 1;
  return function foo() {
    return x;
  };
}

function getTwo() {
  var x = 2;
  return function foo() {
    return x;
  }
}

var f1 = getOne(),
  f2 = getTwo();

console.log(f1 === f2); // false
console.log(f1.toString() === f2.toString()); // true
console.log(f1() === f2()); // false
```

In the example, `f1` and `f2` are function with exactly the same string representations, but one, when called, returns `1` and the other returns `2`. So the only way to correctly compare functions is by their references, i.e. `f1 === f2`.

Comment: Beautiful illustration. That's the kind of answer I was looking for. A case when it will fail. You made my day. That means I should modify the **case "function" : return ((param_objA.toString() === param_objB.toString()) && (param_objA === param_objB) &&  (param_objA() === param_objB()) );**

Comment: Oh no, you don't want to actually invoke the functions! They might have side-effects. I think it should be: `case "function": return param_objA === param_objB;` -- this will suffice. If functions have identical references, they will behave the same when called and will have the same text representation.

Comment: I see. Thank you once again. By the way, what does the word **DzinX** means?

Comment: It means nothing, it's just a fancy half-Polish, half-English writing of the word "jinx". I thought it looked cool when I was 18 ;)

Comment: But you casted a good spell on the question and not an evil. Ironic.

Answer (score 0):

The thinking from the original writer was possibly that objects are only the same if they have the same functions on it.

Is it the correct way? I don't know. There are typically two ways in which object equality is useful: being the same instance and having the same content/values. This code adds the element of checking for the same functionality, but I can't really see where this would help much.